# Last key pressed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to know if a user stop typing?

Something like this:

```
$('#input').onkeyup(function(){
   //do something
});
```

But how you can know if that was the last `.onkeyup` event?

I think that needs a timer, to know when the user stop typing can be 2 seconds after the last `.onkeyup`... Some thing like that.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right... you can use a timer based solution like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //to store the reference to the timer
    var timer;
    $('#myinput').keyup(function () {
        //clear the previous timer
        clearTimeout(timer);
        //create a new timer with a delay of 2 seconds, if the keyup is fired before the 2 secs then the timer will be cleared
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            //this will be executed if there is a gap of 2 seconds between 2 keyup events
            console.log('last')
        }, 2000);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cMTbj/)

Comment: The only line that I don't understand is: "jQuery(function ($) { })" Why you use the $ inside a function parameters? ...